# How to reload Activity from Previous state in Android?

Tags: android

i am creating an app. that contains nos of question and answers.question  and related multiple answers display one by one. i want to keep track of question. if user has complete 3 question and quite from than when user start app again i want to display questions starts from 3 and so on...

for that i have use : android:launchMode="singleInstance"   android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"

this is work but when i completely exit(manually force stop app from app manager) or restart phone than my track is lost..

Any suggetion?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in the onPause() of your ativity, store the current settings to SharedPreferences or SQLite db
- in the onResume() of your activity, load those stored settings and initilise your screen acccordingly.

Loading (in onResume())

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String myvar = sharedPrefs.getString("yourvalue", true);  
... // add others too...
```

Storing (in onPause())

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("yourvalue", value);
// ... add more
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharedpreference to store data for such situation or Sqlite whichever is appropriate...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with sqlite database or storing value in shared preferenc.Just keep the changing state in sqlite/preference.And each time starts the activity you can load from database/preference